# Call method on the element of the array of the different instances in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6, typing

I am using typescript and faced such a problem. I have a list of classes and array of its instances. These classes extends from some basic class. Every class has own methods. I want to call these own methods on element of the array. But right i got an error.

Here is an [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20name%20is%20BasicClass')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child1%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getChildOneSpecialName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20getChildOneSpecialName%20is%20Child1')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child2%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getSpecialName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20special%20name%20is%20Child2')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child3%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getStrangeName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20getStrangeName%20is%20Child1')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Child1()%2C%20new%20Child2()%2C%20new%20Child3()%5D%3B%0D%0Aarray%5B1%5D.getSpecialName()%3B%0D%0Aarray%5B2%5D.getStrangeName()%3B):

```
class BasicClass { 
    getName() { 
        console.log('My name is BasicClass');
    }
}

class Child1 extends BasicClass { 
    getChildOneSpecialName() { 
        console.log('My getChildOneSpecialName is Child1');
    }
}

class Child2 extends BasicClass { 
    getSpecialName() { 
        console.log('My special name is Child2');
    }
}

class Child3 extends BasicClass { 
    getStrangeName() { 
        console.log('My getStrangeName is Child1');
    }
}


const array = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
array[1].getSpecialName(); // Property 'getSpecialName' does not exist on type 'Child1 | Child2 | Child3'.
array[2].getStrangeName(); // Property 'getStrangeName' does not exist on type 'Child1 | Child2 | Child3'.
```

What should I do to make it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) (But snippets don't have built-in support for TypeScript, sadly.)

Comment: I've copied the code into the question for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example, the only way is to make a cast for **every** item. If you want to call the common method for any of them, you can define your array as:

```
const array: Array<BasicClass> = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
array[1].getName(); // correct
```

However, TypeScript now doesn't know that a specific index has a value of class `Child1`, so it doesn't let you call the method. In your case, you'd better cast every time:

```
(<Child2>array[1]).getSpecialName()
```

or you can define the array as `any[]`:

```
const array: any[] = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
array[1].getSpecialName(); // correct
```

This lets you do anything you want, under your own responsibility, but you also lose the compiler's help.

From the talk to T.J I going to point a few questions about type inference in this case.

As T.J. pointed, there is really not need to declare `array` as `Array<BasicClass>` (or `BasicClass[]`, which is the same). If you don't, TypeScript will asume the type of the array to be `(Child1 | Child2 | Child3)[]`.

In this case, if you do `array[0].getName()` it works well. In both cases, TypeScript knows that every element of the array have a method `getName`. If you don't specify the array's type, it knows because `Child1`, `Child2` and `Child3` have such a method (not because they extend `BasicClass`).

However, let's imagine that I define two new classes:

```
class Child4 extend BasicClass {
    getAnotherName() {
        console.log('anything');
    }
}

class Other {
    getName() { console.log('other'); }
    getStrangeName() { }
}
```

Now we define the arrays in both ways:

```
const array1: BasicClass[] = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
const array2 = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
array1[0].getName(); // fine
array2[0].getName(); // fine
```

However, let's do this:

```
array1.push(new Child4()); // fine. Child4 is a subclass of BasicClass
array1.push(new Child4()); // error! Child4 is not compatible with (Child1 | Child2 | Child3)!
```

And if we do:

```
array1.push(new Other()); // Works! Why??
array2.push(new Other()); // also works.
```

If you're wondering why the last example works in both cases, is due to the fact that `Other` is both compatible with `BasicClass` (it has all its methods and properties with the same signatures). And it is also compatible with `(Child1 | Child2 | Child3)` because it is structurally compatible with `Child3`.

However, if you remove the `getStrangeName` method from `Other`, you can still assign it to `BasicClass[]`, because it is still structurally compatible with `BasicClass`. However, assigning it to `array2` will fail, because it is not compatible with either `Child1`, `Child2` or `Child3`.

So, in the end, what matters with types in TypeScript is the **structure** of the type, not the name or whether they derive from each other.

Comment: Obviously no harm in added the type annotation on `array`, but TypeScript happily infers it.

Comment: It does, but it assumes the type as `(Child1 | Child2 | Child3)[]` which is true, but not very neat for my tastes

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking `BasicClass` (the nearest common ancestor). But I'm not all that deep on how TypeScript's type inference works. Do you happen to have a link to something that would tell me it's the "or" instead?

Comment: I think I know out of practice, as I work a lot with TypeScript. In the end, type inference in TypeScript is pretty straigtforward: You declare an array with three objects? Well, then its type is an array of all different types you added. Same with objects. If you define `const ob = {name: string, age: number}` the type of `ob` will be `{name: string, age: number}` as TypeScript uses structural equality when dealing with types. For example, it would allow you to assign an object with type `(Child1 | Child2 | Child3)[]` to a variable of type `BasicClass[]`, as al types have `getName` in common.

Comment: In fact, I'm going to expand my answer to point a few crucial diference between indicating the type to be `Array<BasicClass>` or not doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Cause the array is infered to the type `BasicClass[]` which is actually right. Now basic class has neither a strangeName nor a specialName. Before you can call that you need to check the type:

```
 if(arr[1] instanceof Child2)
   arr[1].getSpecialName()
```

Comment: TypeScript will still complain about the `arr[1].getSpecialName` call.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. I am still getting same tslint error

Comment: strange. isnt instanceof a typeguard?

Comment: @JonasW.: Yes, but TypeScript's compiler doesn't then know that within the `if`, you know that `arr[1]` is a `Child2` even though you know that at runtime. As I said in my answer, you need a cast (if you do this at all, which isn't usually best practice).

Comment: @t.j. but actually *instanceof* is a typeguard http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html. Maybe typescript cant hanlde that in an array.

Comment: @JonasW.: Hence the "yes" at the beginning of my comment, and *"...but TypeScript's compiler doesn't then know..."*.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices:

1. You probably want to refactor that class hierarchy so there's a common method you can call that will get the special or strange or (etc.) name as appropriate to the class:

```
class BasicClass { 
    getName() { 
        console.log('My name is BasicClass');
    }
    getCustomName() {
        return this.getName();
    }
}

class Child1 extends BasicClass { 
    getCustomName() { 
        console.log('My getChildOneSpecialName is Child1');
    }
    // Or keep `getChildOneSpecialName` and have `getCustomName` call it
}

class Child2 extends BasicClass { 
    getCustomName() { 
        console.log('My special name is Child2');
    }
    // Or keep `getSpecialName` and have `getCustomName` call it
}

class Child3 extends BasicClass { 
    getCustomName() { 
        console.log('My getStrangeName is Child1');
    }
    // Or keep `getStrangeName` and have `getCustomName` call it
}


const array = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
array[1].getCustomName();
array[2].getCustomName();
```

You might also add a type annotation to `array`:

```
const array : Array<BasicClass> = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
```

...but [TypeScript happily infers it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20name%20is%20BasicClass')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getCustomName()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.getName()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child1%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getCustomName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20getChildOneSpecialName%20is%20Child1')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Or%20keep%20%60getChildOneSpecialName%60%20and%20have%20%60getCustomName%60%20call%20it%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child2%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getCustomName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20special%20name%20is%20Child2')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Or%20keep%20%60getSpecialName%60%20and%20have%20%60getCustomName%60%20call%20it%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child3%20extends%20BasicClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getCustomName()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('My%20getStrangeName%20is%20Child1')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Or%20keep%20%60getStrangeName%60%20and%20have%20%60getCustomName%60%20call%20it%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Child1()%2C%20new%20Child2()%2C%20new%20Child3()%5D%3B%0D%0Aarray%5B1%5D.getCustomName()%3B%0D%0Aarray%5B2%5D.getCustomName()%3B), though it may be inferring `Child1 | Child2 | Child3` rather than `BasicClass`.

2. Alternately, check the type and cast as appropriate, but this is usually not best practice:

```
const array = [new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child3()];
if (array[1] instanceof Child2) {
    (array[1] as Child2).getSpecialName();
}
if (array[2] instanceof Child3) {
    (<Child3>array[2]).getStrangeName();
}
```

Note that TypeScript offers two ways to cast; I've used both above as examples.

Comment: I can't use 1-st variant, because Child classes have specific methods that shouldn't be in `BasicClass`. I guessed that there is not elegant solution so i will use 2-nd variant. Thank you